How to plot GitLab CI analytics on a specific job, rather than the entire pipeline?
In CI/CD Analytics for GitLab I can profile the run time and failure rate of the pipeline historically over time.
I went to the CI/CD analytics dashboard and hoped to see a way to drill-down and get a more granular view. However, I don't see how to do that for a specific job within the pipeline.
Is that supported? Do I need to use an extension, another piece of software, or the API?
My aim is to gather data on a job that usually runs within a minute or two, but we are getting intermittent reports of the job taking 20+ minutes. I want to analyze that performance historically by plotting all the runs of that job over the past N weeks.
